# Can I initiate a group call to a permanently saved group directly from within MS Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I would like to use MS Teams to repeatedly audio-call the same group of people.

For a single multi-user audio call, I can use the *Chat* tab. In there, I can add participants and initiate a call. In order to call the same group again, that chat can still be found in the "Recent" part of my chat roster, probably unless too much time has passed.

(Alternatively, I can set up a meeting in Outlook, invite all participants, and make it a Teams meeting. For the purpose of this question, that is besides the point as I do not wish to *schedule* my calls for now. Also, participants do not actually receive a "call" here, rather, they have to actively join the group conversation.)

Now, I am wondering whether I can also call a group from a more permanent, named item. The following items came to mind:

- In the "Contacts" part of my chat roster, I have a manually compiled list of all of my contacts, properly grouped into categories. These groups, however, appear to be purely aesthetic in nature, I cannot find any option to perform an action (such as "call") on the entire group.
- In the "Call" tab, I can group contacts, as well. Again, this seems to be purely there for organizing the displayed items, not to do anything to all members of a group at once.
- In the "Teams" tab, I am a part of several teams, each of which has several channels. However, I cannot find any option to call an entire team from here, either.

**Am I missing anything? Is there an option to audio-call a set of contacts that I have grouped in one of the lists with a specific group name?**

Comment: If you invite all the users into a chat, you could call that directly, as you know. If you want to keep that chat - you can pin it, and it'll stick in your Pinned chats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you invite all the users into a chat, you could call that directly, as you know.

If you want to keep that chat - you can pin it, and it'll stick in your Pinned chats.

I can't see any way to call a team, nor a group of contacts in the chat menu, if they are not already in a chat.

You can also re-name a chat, by using the small pencil icon in the chat window (this only appears once there's more than one person in the chat).

Comment: Thank you, upvoted this because at least it solves the issue of the "recent" item presumably disappearing at some point (I suppose pinned chats won't disappear, although it's a bit counterintuitive to have them in the "Recent" section in that case). I won't mark the answer as accepted, though, as I have several such groups, some of which are subsets of others, so seeing only "<first participant> +<number of participants - 1>" is by far not enough for me to identify which group I want to call :-/

Comment: Oh, you can 'name' chats too. That might help?

Comment: Oh, right. Once the chat is open, the main headline does have a little pencil icon that lets me assign a name. That does help indeed (although I now understand even less why Teams features two more or less equivalent concepts, named chatrooms and teams with channels). Could you add a remark about naming chats to the answer to make it complete, please?